# Error occurred when running command 'catkin_make_isolated --install'

Tags: ros, uwsim, catkin-make-isolated

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on UWSim, I want to let a AUV contact with another AUV. Thus I want to make one AUV act as publisher and another one act as subscriber. I add `talker.cpp` and `listener.cpp` by editing `CMakeLists.txt` file shown as below:

```
add_library(uwsim src/osgOceanScene.cpp

......

src/talker.cpp

src/listener.cpp
)
```

then I run command `catkin_make_isolated --install` after sourcing `devel_isolated/setup.bash`.

The error occurred shown as below:

```
==> make -j8 -l8 in '/home/gupta/catkin_ws_2/build_isolated/uwsim'

[  1%] Built target media_files

[  7%] Built target uwsim_plugins_simdev

Scanning dependencies of target uwsim

Linking CXX shared library /home/gupta/catkin_ws_2/devel_isolated/uwsim/lib/libuwsim.so

CMakeFiles/uwsim.dir/src/listener.cpp.o: In function `main':

listener.cpp:(.text+0x163): multiple definition of `main'

CMakeFiles/uwsim.dir/src/talker.cpp.o:talker.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [/home/gupta/catkin_ws_2/devel_isolated/uwsim/lib/libuwsim.so] Error 1

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/uwsim.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2

<== Failed to process package 'uwsim': 

  Command '/home/gupta/catkin_ws_2/install_isolated/env.sh make -j8 -l8' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:

==> cd /home/gupta/catkin_ws_2/build_isolated/uwsim && /home/gupta/catkin_ws_2/install_isolated/env.sh make -j8 -l8

Command failed, exiting.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224771/error-occurred-when-running-command-%27catkin_make_isolated---install%27/) by [ZYS](https://answers.ros.org/users/25674/zys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2016-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Problem is you are adding a main function in each file you are adding. Besides this, I'm not sure if that is what you want to do as you are adding code to the UWSim core and I guess you are not accessing UWSim internal information or modifying its behavior.

But as I said I'm just guessing you do not need to modify UWSim core, so adding a publisher and subscriber to your AUV code should be enough (outside UWSim) unless you want to do something more "realistic" simulating communications through water requiring access to vehicle positions, scene, environment... (In that case I would suggest reading [wiki](http://www.irs.uji.es/uwsim/wiki/index.php?title=Creating_a_new_sensor) it is still incomplete but a good starting point).

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2016-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0